# How to convert Scala play.api.mvc.Result to Java play.mvc.Result in Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play framework (Java), is there a way to convert an object of type play.api.mvc.Result to an object of type play.mvc.Result?

Comment: Maybe you could read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#Results-restructure)

Answer (score 0):

In Play version 2.5.x you should check out `play.core.j.JavaHelpers`. I had to do exactly that conversion i.e. from a Scala `play.api.mvc.Result` to Java `play.mvc.Result`:

It goes like this e.g.

```
import play.core.j.JavaHelpers

def doLogin = Action { implicit request =>
  val jContext = JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request)
  // ...  
  val sResult : play.api.mvc.Result = ...
  val jResult : play.mvc.Result = JavaHelpers.createResult(jContext, sResult)
  // now you can use jResult
}
```